# Symfony2 - Searching for objects by user input

Tags: php, symfony, search, doctrine, twig

I'm trying to search for objects based on words the user types in, but the search results always come up blank. I know the query is right because if I hard-code in a value for $botanicalname, it works. Also, I know the URL is getting the data because here's the URL when I search for "Abies concolor":

"[http://localhost:8000/searchresults?appbundle_shrubs[botanicalname]=Abies+concolor&appbundle_shrubs[commonname]=&appbundle_shrubs[phpreference]=&appbundle_shrubs[save]=&appbundle_shrubs[*token]=SkM70kmkbx-50P*-K5d_FUOnxhaZ4rsfrCnu-nb5WdQ](http://localhost:8000/searchresults?appbundle_shrubs[botanicalname]=Abies+concolor&appbundle_shrubs[commonname]=&appbundle_shrubs[phpreference]=&appbundle_shrubs[save]=&appbundle_shrubs[_token]=SkM70kmkbx-50P_-K5d_FUOnxhaZ4rsfrCnu-nb5WdQ)"

I've also tried the post method ("$botanicalname = $request->request->get('botanicalname')").

Here's my controller:

```
 /**
     * Lists all search results.
     *
     * @Route("/searchresults", name="shrubs_search_results")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function SearchResultsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $botanicalname = $request->query->get('botanicalname');

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.botanicalname = :botanicalname')
            ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%'.$botanicalname.'%')
            ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();

        $shrubs = $query->getResult();

        return $this->render('shrubs/searchresults.html.twig', array(
            'shrubs' => $shrubs,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my html.twig page. It doesn't work with twig syntax, `{{form_widget(form.botanicalname)}}`

It only works with standard HTML `<input type="text" name="botanicalname">`

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to convert your query like below:

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

$shrubs = $query->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname',':botanicalname'))
        ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%'.$botanicalname.'%')
        ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like the getParameter() method in that syntax: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "setParameter" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison"."

Comment: Check the updated query, Forgot to complete the `($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname',':botanicalname'))`

Comment: This time it says: "Attempted to call an undefined method named "getResult" of class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder". No idea why the methods keep becoming undefined.

Comment: Strange, Can you please check update answer again :(

Comment: Now the search results display every single object, not just Abies concolor. Weird!

Comment: Yes, It will display possible results, If you want exact Match of "Abies concolor." Then user needs to search with exact word like "Abies concolor", Other wise result will be not fetched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138931/discussion-between-maulik-savaliya-and-bigmammoo).

Comment: If I search "Abies concolor", the search results display everything in the database. I must have to tweak the query some way...

Comment: It will display using LIKE query of mysql

Comment: If you need exact result then change `$query->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname',':botanicalname'))
        ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%'.$botanicalname.'%')` to `$query->where('p.botanicalname = :botanicalname')
        ->setParameter('botanicalname', $botanicalname)`

Comment: Now it displays no search results again!

Comment: Yes because, You will search by `botanicalname` and i am sure that it will not contains exact 'Abies concolor.'

Comment: That was my original search query

Comment: If search for the exact species name, shouldn't that species appear?

Comment: Even if I search a blank search field nothing shows up

Comment: If the second setParameter parameter is '%'.$botanicalname.'%' then everything shows up, but if it's just $botanicalname then nothing shows up